# Laravel dispatch job doesn't run async, hinders execution

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, queue

so in laravel I have a function that posts some content and pushes a job onto a queue and returns some data from the function(not the queue).

Now I thought that laravel queues were supposed to be some sort of async function that makes sure your code remains quick even though there is a lot of data to handle so you put it in a job. But I noticed that my code still needs to wait till the job is finished before it returns data to the user. Here's a log of the script called 2 times but one is with almost no data in the job, and the other has a lot:

```
[2016-09-08 13:26:50] production.INFO: New alert with Image  
[2016-09-08 13:26:50] production.INFO: Push is send.  
[2016-09-08 13:26:50] production.INFO: Alert data is send back.  
[2016-09-08 13:26:50] production.INFO: New image is valid  
[2016-09-08 13:26:50] production.INFO: Move file for upload  
[2016-09-08 13:26:50] production.INFO: Made it to upload  

[2016-09-08 13:28:50] production.INFO: New alert with Image  
[2016-09-08 13:31:19] production.INFO: Push is send.  
[2016-09-08 13:31:19] production.INFO: Alert data is send back.  
[2016-09-08 13:31:20] production.INFO: New image is valid  
[2016-09-08 13:31:20] production.INFO: Move file for upload  
[2016-09-08 13:31:20] production.INFO: Made it to upload
```

As you can see the second ones takes 4 minutes before the application receives further data. This is a deal breaker you can't make users wait so long. So how do I get the job to run async and the function doesn't have to wait for it to finish.

Here's the line where I call the code:

```
if($isValid === true) {
  $this->dispatch(new SendPushNotificationAlert($alert));

  Log::info('Push is send.');
}
```

And here is my job:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use DB;
use Log;
use App\Alerts;
use App\Users;
use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use App\Http\Controllers\PushNotificationsController as PushNotificationsController;

class SendPushNotificationAlert extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    Protected $alert;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Alerts $alert)
    {
        //
        $this->alert = $alert;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $alert = $this->alert;
        $radius = 10000;
        $earthRadius = 6371000;  // earth's mean radius, m
        // first-cut bounding box (in degrees)
        $maxLat = $alert->lat + rad2deg($radius/$earthRadius);
        $minLat = $alert->lat - rad2deg($radius/$earthRadius);
        // compensate for degrees longitude getting smaller with increasing latitude
        $maxLon = $alert->lon + rad2deg($radius/$earthRadius/cos(deg2rad($alert->lat)));
        $minLon = $alert->lon - rad2deg($radius/$earthRadius/cos(deg2rad($alert->lat)));
        $locations = DB::select("
        SELECT id, lat, lon, user_id, name, radius,
          acos(
            sin(?)*
            sin(radians(lat))+
            cos(?)*
            cos(radians(lat))*
            cos(radians(lon) - ?)
          ) * ? AS distance
              FROM (
                  SELECT id, lat, lon, user_id, name, radius
                  FROM user__locations
                  WHERE lat BETWEEN ? AND ?
                    AND lon BETWEEN ? AND ? AND hide = 0
        ) AS FirstCut
        WHERE acos(
            sin(?)*
            sin(radians(lat))+
            cos(?)*
            cos(radians(lat)
          )*
          cos(radians(lon) - ?)
        ) * ? < ?
        ORDER BY distance", [
          deg2rad($alert->lat),
          deg2rad($alert->lat),
                deg2rad($alert->lon),
          $earthRadius,
                $minLat,
          $maxLat,
          $minLon,
          $maxLon,
          deg2rad($alert->lat),
          deg2rad($alert->lat),
          deg2rad($alert->lon),
          $earthRadius,
          $radius
        ]);

        if(count($locations > 0)) {
          foreach ($locations as $location) {
            if($location->distance < $location->radius) {
              if($alert->anoniem == 0) {
                $user = Users::find($alert->user_id);
                $pushuser = Users::find($location->user_id);
                $pushuser->type = 'location';
                $pushuser->locationname = $location->name;
                $pushusers[] = $pushuser;
              }
                    }
          }
        }
        if(isset($pushusers)) {
          PushNotificationsController::sendPushnotificationsAlert($pushusers, $user);
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone knows why the job doesn't run async and what I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What queue driver do you use?

As described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#introduction you have multiple options but if you use `synchronous` (for local environments only) it'll not run Async.

And does your Job implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue`?

As described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#writing-job-classes you'll see that if you don't implement it the job will run synchronously.

Hope it'll help!

#### EDIT

Saw you already implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue`, so that could not be the problem.

Comment: I'm using sync, but not on a local environment. Going to implement the database driver now and i'll see what happens. Can't believe I missed this.

Comment: A very important part is to change the .env QUEUE_DRIVER to (redis, database, sqs) it's sync by default

Answer (score 6):

I have been getting the same issue in Laravel 5.7. By default, Laravel queue is configured to run synchronously. Open `config/queue.php`, switch to anything else other than `sync`

For example:

```
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'redis'),
```

Alternatively, you can also add this to your .env file.

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
```

Answer (score 2):

For laravel >= 6.14, you can use

```
$array_or_object = [];
YourJobName::dispatchAfterResponse($array_or_object);
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-after-the-response-is-sent-to-browser

To have properly structured job you need

```
php artisan make:job YourJobName
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#generating-job-classes

Example

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;

class YourJobName implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    protected $received_object;    
    public function __construct($received_data)
    {
        $this->received_object = $received_data;
    }    
    public function handle()
    {
        //do_some_thing($this->received_object);
    }
}
```

Find it explained in easy wording: https://divinglaravel.com/running-a-task-after-the-response-is-sent